# How do I save the theme of my app in SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-dark-theme

I have created an app where I can customize the theme and change it from Light to dark using a switch button on the Navigation View Drawer. However I am only able to save the state of the Switch button but not the Theme status.
So please help if there's a problem or there's something I can do to the code to be able to save the dark/ light theme to go hand in hand with the Switch button checked status. The problem is that when I click the switch button everything works fine but when I close the app and open it again the switch button remains checked but the theme goes back to default (light theme). Can someone please help? My codes are as shown below:

Utils Class:

```
public class Utils {
private  static int sTheme;
public final static int THEME_DARK = 1;
public final static  int THEME_LIGHT = 0;
//Set the theme of the Activity and restart the activity
public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {
    sTheme = theme;
    activity.finish();
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
    activity.overridePendingTransition(0,0);
}
//Set the theme of the activity according to the configuration
public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
    switch (sTheme) {
        default:
        case THEME_LIGHT:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.AimBet_Light);
            break;
        case THEME_DARK:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.AimBet_Dark);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Main Activity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

```
SwitchMaterial themeSwitch;

SharedPreferences myPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor myEditor;

private static final String MY_PREFS = "switchPrefs";

private static final String DARK_MODE_SWITCH_STATUS = "switchStatus";

boolean dark_mode_switch_status;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_theme).setActionView(new SwitchMaterial(this));

    themeSwitch = (SwitchMaterial) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_theme).getActionView();

    myPrefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    myEditor = myPrefs.edit();

    dark_mode_switch_status = myPrefs.getBoolean(DARK_MODE_SWITCH_STATUS, false); //false is the default value

    themeSwitch.setChecked(dark_mode_switch_status);

    themeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (themeSwitch.isChecked()) {
                Utils.changeToTheme(MainActivity.this, Utils.THEME_DARK);
                myEditor.putBoolean(DARK_MODE_SWITCH_STATUS, true);
                myEditor.apply();
            } else {
                Utils.changeToTheme(MainActivity.this, Utils.THEME_LIGHT);
                myEditor.putBoolean(DARK_MODE_SWITCH_STATUS, false);
                myEditor.apply();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving any data in the shared prefs. Save it like this inside `onCheckedChangedListener`

```
myEditor.putBoolean(DARK_MODE_SWITCH_STATUS, isChecked)
myEditor.apply()
```

Now for loading theme according to the saved theme preference. Change your `onCreate()` method like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    myPrefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE); // getting shared prefs instance
    boolean isDarkTheme = myPrefs.getBoolean(DARK_MODE_SWITCH_STATUS, false); // getting saved theme status 

    Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this, isDarkTheme); // setting app theme according to the saved theme in shared prefs
    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_theme).setActionView(new SwitchMaterial(this));

    themeSwitch = (SwitchMaterial) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_theme).getActionView();

    myEditor = myPrefs.edit();

    dark_mode_switch_status = isDarkTheme; 

    themeSwitch.setChecked(dark_mode_switch_status);

    themeSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (themeSwitch.isChecked()) {
                Utils.changeToTheme(MainActivity.this, Utils.THEME_DARK);
                myEditor.putBoolean(DARK_MODE_SWITCH_STATUS, true);
                myEditor.apply();
            } else {
                Utils.changeToTheme(MainActivity.this, Utils.THEME_LIGHT);
                myEditor.putBoolean(DARK_MODE_SWITCH_STATUS, false);
                myEditor.apply();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Now in your Utils class, change your `onActivityCreateSetTheme` method like this.

```
public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity, boolean isDarkTheme) {
    if(isDarkTheme) {
        activity.setTheme(R.style.AimBet_Dark);
    }else {
        activity.setTheme(R.style.AimBet_Light);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried what you suggested but it's not working. I have also edited the code so please help if there's a problem or there's something I can do to the code to save the dark/ light theme to go hand in hand with the Switch button checked status. The problem is that when I click the switch button everything works fine but when I close the app and open it again the switch button remains checked but the theme goes back to default (light theme).

Comment: You are not changing the theme on app restart or app opening, I'm updating my answer with that too.

Answer (score 0):

First, save the data to the device when the switch is changed.

```
myEditor.putBoolean(DARK_MODE_SWITCH_STATUS, isChecked)
myEditor.apply()
```

Then, in the onCreate()

```
if(myPrefs.getBoolean(DARK_MODE_SWITCH_STATUS)){
    Utils.changeToTheme(MainActivity.this, Utils.THEME_DARK);
} else {
    Utils.changeToTheme(MainActivity.this, Utils.THEME_LIGHT);
}
```

This really should work. Let me know if there is still a problem! :)

Comment: That did not work also. The app is just stuck on the launch activity and won't open anything else.